# How to find the euclidean distance between X and each sublist of Z using python

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

The points are

```
x=[[0.5697071,0.447144773,0.45310486]]
```

and

```
z=[[0,0.47144773043356025,0],[0,0.47144773043356025,0.4531048568095023],[0.5697070991026062,0.47144773043356025,0.4531048568095023],[0,0,0]]
```

I want a Python code to solve the above problem, I tried using unpacking of lists but I am getting a lot of errors.

Comment: Try `from math import hypot; result = [hypot(*[c_x - c_z for c_x, c_z in zip(x[0], y)]) for y in z]`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

(EDIT: On @Timus's advice - `sum` switched to `math.fsum` to reduce loss of precision)

```
import math

def distance(point1, point2):
    return math.sqrt(math.fsum((dim2-dim1)**2 for dim1, dim2 in zip(point1, point2)))


x=[[0.5697071,0.447144773,0.45310486]]
z=[[0,0.47144773043356025,0],[0,0.47144773043356025,0.4531048568095023],[0.5697070991026062,0.47144773043356025,0.4531048568095023],[0,0,0]]


distances = [distance(each_z, x[0]) for each_z in z]

print (distances)
#result: [0.7283274179145305, 0.5702252305277516, 0.024302957433560483, 0.8542883833737007]
```

Comment: Better use `math.fsum` instead of `sum` to minimize floating point inaccuracies. (And you don't have to use the `[`/`]` brackets in `sum`/`math.fsum` - a generator expression is enough.)

Comment: True - thanks, answer edited accordingly.

Comment: I am getting a TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration

Comment: I've just copied and re-run the code I presented in my answer - it works for me, can you please check to make sure you've run it exactly as provided - no changes or typos?